ufw forwarding of range of ports
I need to forward a range of ports for UDP protocol to a container.
In file before.rules, included a line:
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 --src-range 49000-60000 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.100.100.2

but ufw complains about option --src-range.
How to do this?

The --src-range option 1) is only available if the same command also loads the 'iprange' module using -m iprange, and 2) as the latter name suggests, only takes IP address ranges, not port number ranges. (See the iptables-extensions(8) manual page.)
There's no "range" option for port numbers because the regular --sport option already takes a range of port numbers in the format start:end (e.g. --sport 1000:1999).
(Though if you wanted multiple ranges in a single rule, the 'multiport' module could be useful.)
Additionally, "Source port" is almost always the wrong parameter to match against. UDP streams (as well as TCP connections) are typically sent from a randomized source port which has no meaning – for the initial packet it's the destination port number that actually specifies the service, so "port forwarding" rules normally use --dport instead.
You're also mixing up TCP and UDP (the question says UDP while the rule says -p tcp) but the same answer applies to both.
